# Replace /upgrade libxml2 in xampp 1.7.1 linux

Tags: php, xampp, libxml2

I have xampp 1.7.1 installed on linux, and i need to update libxml2 to version 2.7.3. Can anyone help me? I suppose that i need to recompile php but first i need to install libxml2 and i don't know how.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You can download libmxl2 [here](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) if you want to compile it yourself.

Depending on how up-to-date your distribution is, you may or may not have to compile it yourself.

Comment: yes, i've already downloaded it, but i don't know how to compile it for xampp 1.7.1. And i suppose that after compiling libxml i will need to recompile php, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can now install the new release of xampp. It will include libxml2. http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html